# Переименование ключей массива

Tags: php, массивы

Здравствуйте.

Имеется двумерный массив следующего вида:

```
array(211) {
[0]=>
  array(3) {
    ["name"]=>
    string
    ["type"]=>
    string
    ["id"]=>
    int(54609)
[1]=>
  array(3) {
    ["name"]=>
    string
    ["type"]=>
    string
    ["id"]=>
    int(2849)
[2]=>
  array(3) {
    ["name"]=>
    string
    ["type"]=>
    string
    ["id"]=>
    int(59393)
и т.д. 
}
```

Необходимо ключи массивов первого уровня переименовать в значение `["id"]`, то есть новый массив должен выглядеть так:

```
 array(211) {
[54609]=>
  array(3) {
    ["name"]=>
    string
    ["type"]=>
    string
    ["id"]=>
    int(54609)
[2849]=>
  array(3) {
    ["name"]=>
    string
    ["type"]=>
    string
    ["id"]=>
    int(2849)
[59393]=>
  array(3) {
    ["name"]=>
    string
    ["type"]=>
    string
    ["id"]=>
    int(59393)
и т.д. 
}
```

Как это можно реализовать?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Нужно перебрать существующий массив ($old_arr) и на его основе создать новый ($new_arr).

```
$new_arr = [];
foreach ($old_arr AS $key => $val) {
    $new_arr[$val['id']] = $val;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Для PHP версии 5.5 и выше можно так:

```
$input = array(
    array('id' => 357),
    array('id' => 578),
);

$columnKey = null;
$indexKey = 'id';
$output = array_column($input, $columnKey, $indexKey);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$in=[....];
$out=[];

foreach($in as $value)$out[$value['id']]=$value;
```

Answer (score 0):

Более красивый способ, чем цикл:

```
$result = array_combine(array_column($myArray, 'id'), $myArray);
```